# Turn off password requirement

Tags: users

We are using wordpress internally. We only want the user to login with a username and no password. How would I disable the password requirement when we create a new user account on the backend?

Comment: That may not be possible. Do you have an internal single sign-on service such as CAS, LDAP, or Google? There are plugins that let people sign into WP through those services so they wouldn't have to have an additional password.

Comment: Do you want to remove it from 'Add User' form in dashboard or allow users to log in using logins only?

Comment: Keep in mind that your country may have data protection requirements. If there is any personally identifiable information behind that login you could be found guilty of negligence should a breach occur and an outsider or employee who isn't meant to have access logs in, especially since usernames are not considered secret and are visible via the URLs theme and REST API